# python: better way to handle case sensitivities with df.replace

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have the following code to replace text in my dataframe - dfMSR.

```
oldtxts = ['NA', 'na']
newtxt = 'N/A'
for oldtxt in oldtxts:
    if oldtxt in dfMSR.values: 
        dfMSR = dfMSR.replace(oldtxt, newtxt, regex=True)
    else: 
        print("\nNo {oldtxt} in Dataframe")
```

Is there a better way to replace all cases scenarios without spelling them out or changing the case of all text in the dataframe to upper or lower? In the above code if the user wrote 'Na', it wouldn't be replaced as I haven't included it in oldtxts.

edit: sample data and desired output added

```
dfMSR = pd.DataFrame({'A':['NA','na','O', '', 'N/A'],
          'B':['Anna','E','NA', 'Z', 'Na']})
```

desired output:

```
    A   B
0   N/A Anna
1   N/A E
2   O   N/A
3       Z
4   N/A N/A



Thanks
```

Comment: can you add a sample of your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [case](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) parameter of `str.replace` since you have mentioned `regex=True`

```
dfMSR.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace(r'\bna\b', 'N/A', regex=True,case=False))
```

*Please note that it will not work if it is not Regex-based*

Output:

```
import pandas as pd
dfMSR = pd.DataFrame({'A':['NA','na','O', '', 'N/A'],
          'B':['Anna','E','NA', 'Z', 'Na']})
dfMSR
     A     B
0   NA  Anna
1   na     E
2    O    NA
3          Z
4  N/A    Na
dfMSR.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace(r'\bna\b', 'N/A', regex=True,case=False))
     A     B
0  N/A  Anna
1  N/A     E
2    O   N/A
3          Z
4  N/A   N/A
```

Comment: Arun, I'd read about setting case=False, but it didn't work (*TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'case'*). When I look at the .replace documentation here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html, case is not an option. Also, can you explain what you mean if by "if it is not Regex-based". Thanks

Comment: It's not `pandas.DataFrame.replace` it is [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html). By not regex-based I meant if `regex=False`, you cannot use this option. Please add sample data and expected result. @SModi

Comment: data + result added. To use series.str.replace do I need to do this one column at a time?

Comment: I have updated the answer. No,you dont need to do for one column at a time. It will replaced for all values.@SModi

Comment: Okay. Then you have to first convert it to string with `.astype(str)`. Updated. Please check now @SModi

Comment: unfortunately didn't work. no errors. 'na' didn't get replaced with 'N/A'.

Comment: For me it is working :) @SModi. I ran the same exact code. Updated my output as well

Comment: This worked, but I had to say dfMSR = dfMSR.apply... I noticed that it's replaced what was originally written into excel as 0 with nans. Will confirm that true 0s haven't been replaced before accepting answer.

Comment: No. `0`s will not be replaced with `NaN`s. We are just checking for `na`(_case insensitive_) and replacing the same. Even in your sample data here, there is one `0` and I could see it is not replaced with `NaN`. @SModi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226653/discussion-between-smodi-and-arun-palanisamy).

Answer (score 0):

You can chain `str.lower()` with `.replace` and also, you needn't test the `if` condition as it implicitly done in the replace:

```
dfMSR = dfMSR.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()).replace(oldtxt, newtxt, regex=True)
```

In an example case it would look like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'A':['NA','na','O'],
          'B':['X','E','NA']}).apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()).replace('na','N/A',regex=True)
```

Comment: Celius, I adopted your code to: ```dfMSR.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()).replace('na','N/A',regex=True)
```. If that's correct I got the error: *AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!*. I don't want to convert all columns to dtype string as there's a mix of string, boolean, floats and dates in the data.

Comment: Ah, alright, then if you could tell me the list of columns you'd like to apply I can fix your code to make it work :)

Comment: I will not have a list of columns. The data creator may add new columns and I essentially want to check the entire data set.

Comment: (Also agree, if statement is not needed. I'd inserted it to see if there were any occurrances of the oldtxt - as the data was partially cleaned in earlier stages, processed by someone else. Will be removing from final code.)